# How do i get an object of aggregate values using findByNamedParam?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Am trying to get an object of count(*) and sum() through a hibernate query which actually uses another object.  Here's what I'm doing :

```
String query = select new org.rangde.domain.AggregatedCount(count(*), sum(lps.loanAmount - lps.loanPledged - lps.loanRaised)) from LoanProfileSnapshot lps where  lps.loanState in (:loanStates) 
List<AggregatedCount> counts = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(query, params, values);
return counts.size() > 0 ? counts.get(0) : null;
```

and this is the class AggregatedCount (have removed getters and setters)

```
public class AggregatedCount {
    private int id;
    private BigInteger count;
    private BigDecimal sum;

    public AggregatedCount(){}

    public AggregatedCount(BigInteger count, BigDecimal sum){
        this.count = count;
        this.setSum(sum);
    }
}
```

This is the exception i get when i run the query.

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [org.domain.AggregatedCount] ...  nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [org.domain.AggregatedCount] ...
```

I tried having the sum as Double and BigInteger and still I'm getting the same exception.

Any help would be appreciated. I'd prefer to stick to findByNamedParam for this because there are a lot of conditions that I'm checking within the code before the final query is generated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer seems a little bit too late maybe it will help others ..
The necessary datatype is Long for the count and sum depends on the datatype in the entity.

It also depends on the hibernate version you are using:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide35?_sscc=t

```
public class AggregatedCount {

private Long count;
private Long sum;


   public AggregatedCount(Long count, Long sum){
      this.count = count;
      this.setSum(sum);
   }
```

}